# Specify an Index on a Spring Data TypedAggregation

Tags: java, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

I'm using Spring Data Mongo and one of our aggregations are using the wrong index. I'm using :

- spring-data-mongodb v 1.10.11.RELEASE
- mongo driver 3.6.4
- JAVA 1.8

A simplified version of the code would be something like this :

```
Criteria criteria = createMatch("user", "email");
AggregationOperation userCriteria  = Aggregation.match(criteria);
TypedAggregation<NucleusOccupancySummary> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(User.class,userCriteria);
AggregationResults<NucleusOccupancySummary> aggregationResults = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, User.class, User.class);
```

In this case the aggregation is selecting the wrong index.  I have been able to get it to use the correct index by adding a sort to the query, but this seems like a sloppy way of accomplishing this.

I'm wondering if anyone has had any success with using aggregation or cursor hints (or any other way) to specify the index that should be used for aggregation.

---

Update : As of [Spring Data MongoDB 3.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.3.1) hinting for aggregations are supported by  providing a BSON document as the **hint** on the  **AggregationOptions.Builder**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way to pass the hint to the aggregation query in the spring even though the mongo java driver (`AggregateIterable`) supports it.

Currently `AggregationOptions` supports batchSize, cursor, explain, allowDiskUse and collation.

There is a [jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1836) pending to add hint to the aggregation. You can follow up there.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I was able to extend the AggregationOptions to add the ability to add hints on the aggregation.  I also posted out on the JIRA. I think it would be a relatively small change with big wins

Comment: You are welcome. There is one more change you've to add in the mongoTemplate's  doAggregate method to read the AggregationOptions and set to AggregateIterable.

Comment: user2683814 can you please help me with a working code snippet how is it implemented.